# Trying to return one dataset from a function that prints from two functions

Tags: python, list, csv, input

In this program I am trying get the dataPrinter() function to return just one set of data. Right now the program works well but I would like for it to return just one dataset that includes data from both gen1 and gen2. As shown below, I have already tried creating handler functions that returned each dataset then combining them within a generator. But that didn't work.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Desktop')
fileData = open('SOUTH_06_01_2015_SECFILE.CSV','rb')
##fullSet = open('2015_FILES_COMBINED.CSV','rb')
columns_no = 3

def headerBody(columns_no):
    columns = [] ## returns the created header of a csv file
    for i in range(columns_no):
        text = raw_input("Enter column #%d name: " % i)
        columns.append(text)
    return columns

def dataBody(columns_no):
    segmentLines = [] ## returns the body of the csv file
    for line in fileData.readlines():
        segmentLine = line.split(',')
        segmentLines.append(segmentLine[:columns_no])
    return segmentLines

def dataPrinter(): ## How can I make this function return one set
                   ## of data that combines both the data from
                   ## gen1 and gen2?
    gen1 = headerBody(columns_no)
    gen2 = dataBody(columns_no)
    print','.join(gen1)
    for row in gen2:
        print','.join(row)
dataPrinter()

## Data handlers I  made that give me very limited success ##
def headerHandler():
    gen1 = headerBody(columns_no)
    return','.join(gen1)

def bodyHandler():
    gen2 = dataBody(columns_no)
    for row in gen2:
        return','.join(row)

def combinedPrinter():
    newList = []
    gen1 = headerHandler()
    gen2 = bodyHandler()
    for line in gen1:
        newList.append(line)
    for line in gen2:
        newList.append(line)
    return newList
```

Comment: The function dataPrinter() doesn't seem to be returning anything. It's printing both gen1 and gen2 because you explicitly programmed it so. Can't find anything trivial here or I guess you need to explain more.

Comment: Yes I know. But I am wondering how I can make so that another function returns both datasets combined in one.

Comment: Ok. Posting response as answer.

Comment: Ok great. You can see from the handlers in the lower part of the code that I am trying to combine the output from both headerBody() and dataBody()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best part in Python is that creating new objects on the fly is very easy. You can make a method return a tuple of two values.

```
def dataPrinter(): 
    gen1 = headerBody(columns_no)
    gen2 = dataBody(columns_no)
    return gen1, gen2
```

And from the calling side, you can get them either as a single tuple object or unpack into two variables.

```
response = dataPrinter()
print response[0] # prints header
print response[1] # prints body
```

Or alternatively

```
header, body = dataPrinter()
print header
print body

print header + '\n' + body
```

Extra Trivia:-
How to swap values of two variables in python?
`a,b = b,a`. That's it.